# GWT event not working on an element added in runtime

Tags: events, gwt, element, celltable

- I create a new CellTable.
- Override the onBrowserEvent2 to handle mouse events.
- Add a new element to the table.

Sadly the event listener is not working on the added element. It's only working on the initial elements.

```java
table = new CellTable<Contact>() {

    public void onBrowserEvent2(Event event) {
    Element tr = Element.as(event.getEventTarget());

    boolean gotIt = false;
    while (!gotIt && tr != null) {
        if (!tr.getTagName().equals("TR")) {
        tr = tr.getParentElement();
        continue;
        }
        gotIt = true;
    }

    if (tr == null)
        return;

    tr = Element.as(tr.getChild(1));

    Element out = DOM.createDiv();
    out.setInnerHTML("<a href='xxx'>Edit contact</a> | <a href='xxx'>Add visit plan</a> | <a href='xxx'>New visit</a>");

    switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
    case Event.ONMOUSEOVER:
       tr.appendChild(out);
        break;
    case Event.ONMOUSEOUT:
       tr.getChild(1).removeFromParent();
        break;
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: When you say 'not working', what exactly do you mean? Please can you be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with it you can have all your handlers declared separately.

You can always add Mouse Handlers directly like this:

//code depicting a MouseOverHandler. Use this for any type of GWT Event Handler

```
            CellTable<String> cellTable = new CellTable<String>();

            cellTable.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
                    // Your logic
                }
            }, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```

That should help